# How to connect using Putty to ubuntu in a virtual machine(VMWare)

Tags: ssh, vmware, putty

I can not connect to the virtual machine. I have read a lot of information, but it still does not work. Perhaps the problem is that when I prescribe in the console `ifconfig` I see:

[image: that]

In many examples, it says `eth1`, `eth0`, but I have a `ens33`. 
Also, the address from image doesn't ping (in CLI Windows).

Virtual Machine settings are:

[image: here]

[image: here]

When I try connect from Putty to VM (input ip address and port. No more settings made) I get this exception:

[image: Image 4]

I read a lot of answers from stackovwerflow, but most often answers is install `openssh-server` (done), check port(done, it's 22), try in Ubuntu CLI `ssh -p22 user@localhost`(done, it's work). Also in Ubuntu CLI `service ssh status` (done, status enable)

Comment: Your first VMware screenshot shows that you have configured a custom Host-only Network, but the second VMware screenshot shows that you are using NAT for the virtual interface. Use VMnet0 instead. Is your host IP address in the subnet 192.168.84.0?

Comment: @muclux ty for answer. `Is your host IP address in the subnet 192.168.84.0?` How I can check it?

Comment: @muclux I changed network connection to Custom VMnet0, and now, when I write `ifconfig` ip is  192.168.84.128, but error is the same(connect to 192.168.84.128 22 port)

Comment: What is the address of your host system?

Comment: I write ifconfig in Windows cmd. And it haven't adapter with 192.168.84.0 address.

Comment: @muclux I don't now how to find it `What is the address of your host system?`. I also write `ifconfig` in Windows cmd. But it have a lot of adapter with other ip address

Comment: Then why did you configure the 192.168.84 subnet for your custom VMnet0?

Comment: it was standart value

Comment: @muclux 192.168.1.9 is my address

Comment: @muclux I tried insert this ip into VMnet0, but it have error with mask. I tried 192.168.1.0. But it doesn't work(

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while browsing about a similar problem. I was running `Ubuntu` on a virtual machine and `Kali Linux` as the host OS. I used the `ens33` **inet** address and was able to get access to my virtual Ubuntu. Using both `PuTTY SSH Client` and `ssh` command as shown below. [image]